# Calculating a user rank

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, algorithm, statistics

Suppose I have a table `UserStatistics` with following columns:

```
UserId (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
ViewCount (BIGINT)
SubscriberCount (BIGINT)
Rank (INT)
```

1. What would be the best way to give a rank of 1-10 or 1-5 to millions of users in the database?
2. What would you recommend? 1-10 or 1-5 or something else? Why?

EDIT:

I would like to put more weight on the `SubscriberCount` than `ViewCount`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the rank you could use [ntile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) like this.

```
select *, 
 ntile(5) over(order by ViewCount+SubscriberCount) as CalculatedRank
from UserStatistics
```

If you want rank values to 1-10 and more weight on `SubscriberCount` you can modify the query like this.

```
select *, 
 ntile(10) over(order by ViewCount+SubscriberCount*2) as CalculatedRank
from UserStatistics
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achive with this ranking...

If you just want to group people in some rough groups then 1-5

If you want to apply some subtle differences then you should go with 1-10

It's just purely based on the context in which you analyse the rankig further in your application